# Covering exposed contacts on a toggle switch

Tags: switches, enclosure, mount, toggle-switch

I need to mount a mini toggle or rocker switch to the outside surface of a box. For various reasons I cannot drill a hole, so the entire switch needs to be freestanding or glued to the surface. (There is a small hole for the wires to go into the box, but that's it.)

I remember seeing self-contained switches with nice plastic back covers, but I can't find any such components on the market. Can anyone recommend a good way to cover up the exposed contacts and even provide a nice flat surface?

Comment: How big is the hole for the wires?  There are toggle switches that only require a 3/16 inch hole.

Comment: @Barry the position of the existing hole is not where I want to place the switch

Answer (score 3):

Use heat-shrink tubing.  Use a small size that will shrink to a snug fit on the wires and terminals, and a larger size to cover the body of the switch, and extend over the wires.

If the switch carries 120 or 240 VAC, I would prefer to add a box to contain the switch and wires, but the heat-shrink technique should be OK (not ideal) for low voltage.

Comment: The switch will indeed be carrying 120 VAC, so it sounds like a box of some kind is a better idea. The trouble is finding something compact.